# How can one convert an image file stored as a clob into a blob and insert it into a different table?

Tags: oracle, blob, postgresql, clob

Using Oracle

How can one convert an image file stored as a clob into a blob and insert it into a different table?

I already have code pulling a blob image out and displaying it on my website but I cannot figure out how to get the clob and convert to blob so I can put it in the new scheme and table I need too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle provides a  build in package called DBMS_LOB that handles most LOB operations, one of the methods in this package is DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1020355

Please mind that sometimes you'll need to specify the CHARSET.

you can look at the example here:
http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2008/04/convert-clob-to-blob.html

If this wasn't helpful you can always use UTL_RAW